# How to import a function from a file into a jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I have a python file that from this book on [deep learning and go](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-and-the-game-of-go) that looks as below. If I do a python.exe bot_v_bot.py, the program runs.

If I run  bot_v_bot.py from eclipse/pydev then it works.

The .ipnb file is in the same folder as the bot_v_bot.py.

If i put:

```
from bot_v_bot import main
main()
```

into a cell in the .ipnb file and run it, it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-248b35949c67> in <module>()
----> 1 from bot_v_bot import main
      2 main()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot_v_bot'
```

edit: the code below worked. eclipse has src on the python path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('src')
from bot_v_bot import main
main()
```

file: bot_v_bot.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
# tag::bot_vs_bot[]
from dlgo import agent
from dlgo import goboard_slow
from dlgo import gotypes
from dlgo.utils import print_board, print_move
import time


def main():
    board_size = 9
    game = goboard_slow.GameState.new_game(board_size)
    bots = {
        gotypes.Player.black: agent.naive.RandomBot(),
        gotypes.Player.white: agent.naive.RandomBot(),
    }
    while not game.is_over():
        time.sleep(0.3)  # <1>

        print(chr(27) + "[2J")  # <2>
        print_board(game.board)
        bot_move = bots[game.next_player].select_move(game)
        print_move(game.next_player, bot_move)
        game = game.apply_move(bot_move)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# <1> We set a sleep timer to 0.3 seconds so that bot moves aren't printed too fast to observe
# <2> Before each move we clear the screen. This way the board is always printed to the same position on the command line.
# end::bot_vs_bot[]
```

Comment: If you run import bot_v_bot what is the output? ModuleNotFoundError again?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot_v_bot'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check and ensure that your module is present under any one of the system path (sys.path)

sys.path values can be retrieved by the following code.

```
import sys
sys.path
```

If the path of the module is not added in the sys.path, we can append the path in sys.path by

```
sys.path.append('C:\\') # sample path C:\\
```

Comment: ['',
 'd:\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'd:\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'd:\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'd:\\Anaconda3',
 'd:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'd:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'd:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'd:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'd:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\ray\\.ipython']

Comment: Please provide the path of your module present. Is it already present in the sys.path?

Comment: Please add the path of the module in sys.path